# iATS Charge to Card on File attributed to merged/deleted record

Tags: iats

What happened:
1: Went to recurring series. Clicked "Process" on Card on File
2: Put in the amount, left defaults
3: Charge went to iATS and posted successfully.
4. The charge linked to a formerly merged/deleted record of the same name as the record it was supposed to be processed on, unlinked to the recurring contribution.

What could have caused this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! The contact_id in civicrm_iats_customer_codes was linked to the wrong contact. Previously the records were merged and one was soft-deleted, so in our import process that was confused. Should be a simple fix!

Comment: Correct process would have been to export the exisiting recurring series in progress -> the contact id-s in that file would have been the only contact id-s associated with any recurring series. If you ran a dedupe match process instead there very likely are more issues.

Answer (score 1):

This tells me there are issues with the way in which you have migrated your recurring series from PayPal to iATS Payments and into CiviCRM.